# DropdownList SelectedItem is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm facing a very strange problem when trying to get the selected value of a DropDownList. I have the following controls on my page: 4 DropDownList, 2 textboxes, 6 ListBoxes and a button.
At the moment to click on the button all the controls preserve its data I can access them from code behind. buut there is one control that doesn't behave in the same way. It's one of the 4 DropDownlist. When trying to do the following it just get a empty string:

```
string sData1 = this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue;  --> works OK
string sData2 = this.DropDownList2.SelectedValue;  --> works OK
string sData3 = this.DropDownList3.SelectedValue;  --> works OK
string sData4 = this.DropDownList4.SelectedValue;  --> is NOT working
```

Basically this is the HTML markup I have for each DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownLis1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownLis2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownLis3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownLis4" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I've searching on the Internet to see if there is something related but without no luck.
Another doubt I have is the following. Is there any possibility that the viewstate is full and it doesn't store the selected value of that DropDownList?

Any clue or help would very appreciate
Thanks

Comment: Hi. yes it's C# .net. I just remove the () that were after the SelectedValue property. I mistyped them. Anyway, it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Try to check to see if AutoPostBack is turned on for DropDownList4

Comment: Please add the front end (html) code that has the controls.

Comment: Done. I just have updated the original post.

Comment: how you bind data to droupdown lists? please update question with that code